# SONAR - Analyzing source code in an Incremental way

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using sonar for the last few months and want to know that do sonar works in an incremental way or not i.e if i do soanr analysis for the first time on my project code it will definitely analyze all the code but if i do some enhancement on my core source code and update some files then after updation do sonar analysis again on the same code then will sonar analyze all the files OR only analyze files which i have updated?
I am using "Sonar way with Findbugs" as my default quality profile.

Is there any way to use sonar in an incremental way, to analyze only updated files?
Is this possible in sonar or not?

Kindly revert your help will be appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Sonar does not currently handle incremental analyses.

If you want, you can watch and vote for the following ticket: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2815

Answer (score 3):

If your task if code quality metrics in a general way, then you can use these tools directly on Jenkins. See [FindBugs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin) , [PMD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin) or [Checkstyle Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin). They independently give what you need in the form of "**incremental code**" reports. But if you have to use SONAR only, then Fabrice's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here the post where the ticket that @fabrice-sonar-team comments was born:

[does Sonar support Incremental code quality analysis](http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/does-Sonar-support-Incremental-code-quality-analysis-tp3160423p3160433.html)

You can read Freddy Mallet's explanation about why this functionality is not trivial to be implemented. It requires lot of effort, so as Fabrice said, vote for the ticket! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on since this is the first google result for 'Sonar incremental preview analysis' in stack, and the answers are way too old.

Sonar has plugins available for IDEs such as Eclipse and NetBeans that can run incremental analysis on the changed files alone. This still needs a connection the SonarQube server though.

You may also run the analysis right from Jenkins by passing an additional sonar analysis property -  `sonar.analysis.mode=incremental`in your Sonar scan build step. This will report the code quality in a full report - will all code issues as well as a light report  containing only new issues (since last full scan as recorded in server).

To take one step further use `sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true` and publish the generated html reports to your Jenkins build page - Neat and Trim

Sonar documentation [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/#more-8878)